# npm install fails on an uglify-js folder that is emptying during its execution

Tags: node.js, node-modules, uglifyjs

I'm entering a project where *npm* produces an issue for a long time, and none have the knowledge of when and why it appeared. I would like to have some clues on where (or what) to search.

a simple `mvn clean install` performs an `npm install` after having installed the *npm* plugin.

I can see that his work involves the creation (or the presence) of a link that will makes a directory
`target/node/node_modules/uglify-js` targeting `~/front-end/uglify-js/`

this last one appearing to be a source folder (?) of our project, or something needed by `npm` (I don't know *uglify* myself). As I can see:

```sh
find  ~/front-end/target/node/node_modules -type l -ls
3096224744204072      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 me  1049089       101 Oct 18 09:20 /c/Users/front-end/target/node/node_modules/uglify-js -> /c/Users/front-end/uglify-js/
```

That folder `~/front-end/uglify-js/` is initially carrying files `package.json`, `index.js` and `link-package.js`

But when `npm install` takes place, it fails on an `addLocal` internal step.

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm (npm install) @ front-end ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = install
[DEBUG]   (f) installDirectory = C:\Users\front-end\target
[DEBUG]   (f) npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven = true
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.front-end:front-end:10.7.14-xxx_yyyyy @ C:\Users\front-end\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) repositorySystemSession = org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession@585c13de
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@187eb9a8
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipTests = false
[DEBUG]   (f) workingDirectory = C:\Users\front-end
[DEBUG]   (f) execution = com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm {execution: npm install}
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\front-end
[ERROR] npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\front-end\uglify-js
[ERROR] npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\front-end\\target\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\front-end\\target\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v10.24.1
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
[ERROR] npm ERR! code EISDIR
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno -4068
[ERROR] npm ERR! syscall read
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
[ERROR] npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
[ERROR] npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
[ERROR] npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
```

What I can see after this failure happens, it's that there is an existing folder `~/front-end/uglify-js/` on my disk, but that it is now empty : it has been recreated.
And the `npm-debug.log` gives no other information than the one upper.

If I restore the missing files (`package.json`, `index.js`, `link-package.js`) in that directory and retry `mvn clean install` this problem won't reproduce.
As if it was occurring only one time per day? Humm... Unsure...

Our *node* and *npm* version are : `node v10.24.1` and `npm v2.15.12`.

Comment: Did you address this error `eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`

Comment: @Mr. The problem is that there are no clues about what kind of illegal operation has been attemted, and on which directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually found that it's a *Maven* issue that is the cause of our trouble.

It doesn't honor it's `<followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>` settings and follows it whatever, and during the removal of a link file in `target` directory, `npm` causes (by *Maven*) the deletion of the file source of the link.